# a persistence and startup service to support an app

Tags: android

I own an android 4.0.3 tablet and I'm programming in Java/SDK, still not tried NDK.
Now, suppose that you want to program this tablet to put it in a service point, with a single use case, like a restaurant, where it would show menus and let the user pass them. I would like not to let the user to shut down this software. Also, it must automatically runs at tablet start up and persisnts on, i.e. if it shuts down by some reason, the tablet should not go back to its standard GUI but to restart this application.

I don't know any start point for this, like some keywords etc. I imagine that here I must code a service (that maintains the persistence and startup of the application) and the application itself.

Could you please give some ideas / keywords / potential start points / comments?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here some things you need to check:

1.) How to start an application at boot.

2.) How to run a service/thread in background to check if the application is running and if not to start it.

3.) How to deactivate buttons, ie like the "back" button to not exit the app or program a way that the activity never exits with user interference. (That is very bad practice though!) :)

4.) There should be a way to exit the application though for maintenance purposes. Be creative in that one. Maybe exit only with password or something.

Comment: Thank you for helping points, is that practically possible to prevent Android tablet to show its GUI at all, on start up? I want the user to - when powering tablet on - see the GUI of my program. Is this automatically done when in boot chain the service starts this app? p.s. for the ability to stop the program: that service receives commands via wifi, so the service itself would be under control.

Comment: Like CommonsWare said below, in that case a homescreen replacement would be best.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to not to let the user to shut down this software so it must persist.

Make it be the home screen.

> Also, it must automatically runs at tablet start up and persisnts on, i.e. if it shuts down by some reason, the tablet should not go back to its standard GUI but to restart this application and represent its GUI.

Make it be the home screen.

Comment: WOW your response :) Thanks, "home screen" was why I made this post. Thanks again and thank you all :)